# .Net Inherited Control Property Default

Tags: .net, inheritance, properties, default

Im trying to make a simple "ButtonPlus" control. the main idea is to inherit from the button control and add some default property values (such as font,color,padding...)

No matter how i try, the WinForm always generates (or "serializes") the property value in the client forms

the whole point is to have minimal and clean code, not that every instance of the buttonPlus should have 5 lines of init code.

I want that the form designer should not generate any code for theses properties and be able to control them from the ButtonPlus code. In other words, if I change the ForeColor from red to blue only 1 single bingle line of code in the app should change.

heres my code so far. as you can see, ive tried using defaultvalue, reset , shouldserialize.... anything i was able to find on the web!

`Public Class ButtonPlus`

```
Inherits Button

Sub New()        
    AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(177, Byte))
    Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3)
    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Top
    ForeColor = Color.Aqua
End Sub

<DefaultValue(True)> _
Public Overrides Property AutoSize() As Boolean
    Get
        Return MyBase.AutoSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        MyBase.AutoSize = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function ShouldSerializeAutoSize() As Boolean
    Return False ' Not AutoSize = True
End Function

Public Function ShouldSerializeForeColor() As Boolean
    Return False 'Not ForeColor = Color.Aqua
End Function

Public Overrides Sub ResetForeColor()
    ForeColor = Color.Aqua
End Sub
```

End Class

Thank you very much for taking the time to look this over and answer
all the best

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want WinForms theming, which is not a built-in thing right now, unfortunately. However, there are some third-party implementations.

Check out the ThemeManager class in [The Genghis Project](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/genghis/) to give you a framework for doing this on a very high-level or more granular scale. It does, however, provide what you are asking for.

Comment: Also, this will allow you to do this for many other controls (comboboxes, etc.) without having to inherit each and every control yourself. It's VERY handy!